# Is there a way to pipe stdout in my python3 script to a pager command like less

Tags: python-3.x, io

I routinely have to type:

> my-python-command | less -S

I would love it if I could get that behavior from my-python-command without having to pipe it.  my-python-command uses the print() function to send its output to the terminal so I was hoping for a way to simply tell it "redirect stdout so it goes to the less command (with an argument)"

I have not been able to find an example similar to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: look at python logger and pygogo. You can log as you please and add predefined and customized output. It may meet your needs. It won't be as simple as piping to less, but you can mimic the functionality.